# Jquery - continuing an animation with a timer - unclear about how animation works

Tags: jquery, animation, timer

Here is my code for a mouseover:

```
$('.caption').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow',1);
    $(this).css('color','#ddd').animate({'color': 'white'}, 500); 
    $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
});

$('.caption').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow',0.9);
    $(this).css('color','white').animate({'color': '#ddd'}, 500); 
    $(this).css('font-weight','normal');
});
```

I have four boxes that this works with, all with the class .caption.  I would like to make these actions rotate between the four of them with a certain number of seconds pause (say, 5) before moving to the next one. In other words, the mousedown effects (without having a mousedown), wait 5 seconds, mouseup effect, then move to the 2nd .caption, and do the same... etc.

Here is where I am, 45 minutes later or so.

```
function doRotate(num) {

    var len = 3; // starts at 0
    var index = num;

    $('div .nav-piece').each = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('div .nav-piece').eq(index).animate({
                backgroundColor: "white"
            }, 500);
        }, 500);

        setInterval(function() {
            $('div .nav-piece').eq(index).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#cfc4c3"
            }, 500);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
 <div id="nav-container">
        <div id="piece1" class="nav-piece">
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/bg_example.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                <div class="caption overlay-top">Text example</div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div id="piece2" class="nav-piece">
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/bg_example.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                <div class="caption overlay-bottom">Text example</div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div id="piece3" class="nav-piece">
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/bg_example.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                <div class="caption overlay-top">Text example</div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div id="piece4" class="nav-piece">
            <div style="background-image: url('assets/bg_example.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                <div class="caption overlay-bottom">Text example</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

doReady is called at document.ready.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using? What calls doRotate?

Comment: @j08691 Just edited it in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use mouseenter/mouseleave or mouseover/mouseout in combination, not a mix of the two behaviors

This will achieve what you want. Each caption is executed in the callback from the prior animation. We use queue to put the element's into the fx queue (the only place delay() works).

I'd throw this on fiddle, but fiddle seems to be in read-only mode today! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title>test url stuff</title>


   <style type="text/css">
      .caption { width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: 20px; padding: 5px; float: left; }
      .red { background-color: red; }
      .blue { background-color: blue; }
      .yellow { background-color: yellow; }
      .green { background-color: green; }
      .black { background-color: black; }
   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function($) {
      var
         // how long should it animate?
         howLong = 1000,

         // apply the font-weight when animation completes
         mouseInProps = {duration: 500, complete: function() { $(this).css('font-weight','bold');} },

         mouseOutProps = {duration: 500,
            complete: function() {
               var $this = $(this);
               // apply the font-weight when animation completes
               $this.css('font-weight','normal');
               if( $this.next().length ) {
                  // this makes them successively call the next element and animate it
                  // by using the complete: callback on animate's props
                  queueOne($this.next());
               }
            }
         };

      function queueOne($e) {
         $e.queue(function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1).animate({'color': '#fff'}, mouseInProps).dequeue();
         })
         // make the queue pause x seconds
         .delay(howLong)
         // apply the mouseleave effects
         .queue(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', .9).animate({'color': '#ddd'}, mouseOutProps).dequeue();
         });
      }

      queueOne($('.caption').first());
   });
</script>

<div class="caption red">one</div>
<div class="caption green">two</div>
<div class="caption blue">three</div>
<div class="caption yellow">four</div>
<div class="caption black">five</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, it looks like the items get added to different queues. There is an option in 1.7 to drop them into the same queue which would be a bit more elegant than callbacks; are you on >= 1.7? I'll correct my example either way.

Comment: Okay, and what version of jQuery UI? (which is required to animate background colors)

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it's only animating the first one now.  Strange that it works for you... I'll try to take it from here, unless you know of a quick fix.  I'd owe you a coffee, except that I can't pipe one through the internet. :)

Comment: Huh, that is strange. Well let me know what you find out!

Comment: I discovered that it produces a memory error in IE. The only way I could correct it was to upgrade to jQuery 1.5.1 or higher; you should try that with the example and see if it solves your issues too.

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately that does not fix it.

Comment: Here's something new. `queueOne($('.nav-piece').first());` this makes it rotate through once. I also updated jquery to 1.5 for now.

Comment: It should, btw, only rotate through once; did you want it to continuously cycle or something?